# laravel undefined variable in blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble accessing a variable passed to a view in laravel blade.

I've had no problems before - in this case though I'm setting the variable and using a redirect as follows:

```
return Redirect::route('members.create')
                ->withInput()
                ->with('test1', 'Email address already exists.');
```

Then in my view i'm trying to echo out the result as follows:

```
{{ (isset($test1) ? $test1 : "No Error" )}}
```

I know the error message exists as I can see it set in the profiler but any attempts to access $test1 gets an error: `undefined variable`

I'm doing something very basic but obviously making a basic erro

Can someone help and tell me what is my schoolboy error!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for your variable using the static `get` method in **`Session`**.

Comment: YES! YOUr right the variable was in a session as flash data. I hadnt understood that a redirect `with` uses a session as opposed to `View::make()->with()` is passed as a variable. I was able to access the variable using: `Session::get('test1')` Thanks

Answer (score 2):

is that the exact code? As it doesn't add up - you can't get `undefined variable` if you are checking `isset($test1)`.

Do a search for `$test1` in your view to see if you are trying to call it anywhere else without an `isset` check.

Also double check you haven't done something silly like written `$test` instead of `$test1`

Comment: Hi - not 100% I copied over the relevant code. You are correct the error occurs with trying to echo without the check if the value is set. But the problem relates the the variable not being available when it should. or so I thought...